# Problem in calculating inverse of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$

I wanted to calculate its inverse.

I done following

$f(x)=y$ and using quadratic formula evaluate x in term of y.

i.e $x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$ but solution is its reciprocal .I thought hard But I think I am making silly mistake. Please Help me out .

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: No, the solution of the OP is not correct : it works only if it has been specified _right at the beginning_  that he/she restricts the domain to $(-1,1)$. Or to $(-\infty,-1)$, or to $(1,+\infty)$ but in this case it is not at all the same inverse function. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you made no mistake: your solution is correct, assuming that the domain of $f$ is $(-1,1)$. Note, however, that\begin{align}\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}&=\frac{\left(-1+\sqrt{1-4y^2}\right)\left(-1-\sqrt{1-4y^2}\right)}{2y\left(-1-\sqrt{1-4y^2}\right)}\\&=\frac{4y^2}{2y\left(-1-\sqrt{1-4y^2}\right)}\\&=-\frac{2y}{1+\sqrt{1-4y^2}}.\end{align}

Comment: See my comment to the OP and my answer.

Comment: It is correct, of course. I suppose that it is the restriction to $(-1,1)$ that matters here.

Comment: It is an assumption that, as an educator, I think compulsory to indicate to a student.

Comment: Nice point. I've edited my first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $$x=\frac{y}{1-y^2}$$ or
$$x-xy^2=y$$ or
$$xy^2+y-x=0,$$ which gives
$$y=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}$$ or $$y=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}.$$
Now, we need to choose the right answer.

On $(-\infty,-1)$ and on $(1,+\infty)$ the second function is valid,

but on $(-1,1)$ we get that $g(x)=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}$ is an inverse function to $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but this function, as a whole, has no inverse because it is not bijective : see figure below (the curve has three branches in black).

[image]

You have, **at first**, to select a branch. Consider for example the central one, which corresponds to a function from $(-1,1)$ to $(-\infty,+\infty)$. The resulting function (graphical representation in red, *symmetrical of the central branch* with respect to 1st quadrant line bissector) has equation :

$$x=f(y)=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y} \tag{1}$$

(for $y \neq 0$) and $f(0)=0$.

which is one you have obtained.

But if you select another branch, for example the left one, which corresponds to a function with domain $(-\infty,-1)$ and range $(0,\infty)$ you would have another expression than (1) for the inverse function.